# Any idea why this xpath isn't working?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Here's is the html elements and the command I'm running which is checking if "lol" exists on the page. It's not finding "lol" and not sure why.

```
<svg data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.1.0" height="2129" width="1252">
  <g data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.1.0.$http=2//10=1203=167=127=29090/img/103?token=0a11944b491366ab96caf34c8e3991d436c86d655">
    <image height="2129px" width="1252px"xlink:href="http://10.203.67.27:9090/img/103?token=a11944b491366ab96caf34c8e3991d436c86d655">
  </g>
  <g data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.1.0.1">
     <line class="severity-inactive " data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.1.0.1.$conn2" y2="1209.895121951221" x2="677.0326086956554" y1="708.8012195121894" x1="1126.1195652173908" style="stroke-width: 7;">
     <line class="severity-inactive " data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.1.0.1.$conn4" y2="329.7353658536632" x2="841.593360995849" y1="708.8012195121894" x1="1126.1195652173908" style="stroke-width: 7;">
  </g>
  <g data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.1.0.2">
    <g data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.1.0.2.$node4">
      <circle class="severity3 " data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.1.0.2.$node4.0" r="9.674435999999993" cy="708.8012195121894" cx="1126.1195652173908">
      <g data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.1.0.2.$node4.1">
         <rect class="node-label-background"  data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.1.0.2.$node4.1.0" height="21" width="22" y="716.8012195121894" x="1115.1195652173908">
         <text class="node-label" data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.1.0.2.$node4.1.1" y="721.3012195121894" x="1118.1195652173908">lol</text>
    </g>
 </g>


 By.xpath(//*[name()='svg']/*[name()='text' and text()='"+lol+"'])
```

Comment: Do you mean `By.xpath("//*[name()='svg']/*[name()='text' and text()='"+lol+"']")` (with extra quotes just inside the brackets)? If so, what is the value of your `lol` variable?

Comment: The value of lol is lol as seen here: <text class="node-label" data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.1.0.2.$node4.1.1" y="721.3012195121894" x="1118.1195652173908">lol</text> For some reason its just not finding it

Comment: So turns out I wasn't switching to the iframe which contained all the HTML above which is why I wasn't seeing any values and struggling. Fixed now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is correct xpath:

```
By.xpath("//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='text' and text()='lol']")
```

Add quotes, use 'lol' string (not variable) and add second slash before `text` element locator (this is not svg's direct child).

Comment: Still not working sadly. I'm wondering if doing `/preceding-sibling::circle[@class='severity3']` at the end is needed here. The xpath is returning valid but for some reason its not finding 'lol'. And lol = lol.

Comment: Interesting, it works perfectly for me, I've just checked it again (after adding two extra closing tags for `<g>`). However, I tried it in browser's console using `$x()`, not selenium, if that makes any difference. Are you 100% sure that this markup is present on the page when you look for it? Can you paste the exact error/assertion failure you get?

Comment: Yes the html above shows the text itself and I confirmed its existence in the dom as well. The error is just a framework produced error message indicating false or 'lol' not found so thats it. What do u mean after adding two extra closing tags?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a '/'

Yours: `By.xpath(//*[name()='svg']/*[name()='text' and text()='"+lol+"'])`

Mine : `By.xpath(//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='text' and text()='"+lol+"'])`

Comment: Still not working sadly. I'm wondering if doing `/preceding-sibling::circle[@class='severity3']` at the end is needed here. The xpath is returning valid but for some reason its not finding 'lol'. And lol = lol.

Comment: Another thing is that your XML is not really valid, I had to close many elements that are left open in order for the xpath to work. Maybe if you fix these, the xpath will then work ?

Comment: I expanded the elements just so they could be seen really. The first two `g data-reactid`'s

Answer (score 0):

How about
`//svg//text[contains(text(),'lol')]`

(selecting `//*` for the sake of one tag, whose name is known to you (`svg`) is quite inefficient, selecting it directly is much better; similarly in case of `text` - you already know the name of tag, so just use it; finally `contains` takes care of the fact that searched text may only be part of the entire text)

Comment: Still not working sadly. I'm wondering if doing `/preceding-sibling::circle[@class='severity3']` at the end is needed here. The xpath is returning valid but for some reason its not finding 'lol'. And lol = lol.

Comment: @Shawn: the xpath above would select the entire element (i.e. `<text class="node-label" data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.1.0.2.$node4.1.1" y="721.3012195121894" x="1118.1195652173908">lol</text>`). To check the text you can use getText(): `WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(...)); String text = element.getText();`
Maybe post a snippet of your code for us to see what you are trying to achieve

Comment: sadly the assert.verify code is so buried within the heigharhcy of the framework its hard to put it here. I'm thinking I need to call "g" maybe?

Comment: @Shawn: Without code I cannot say anything specific, but imo xpath is not your problem, it looks correct based on html snippet that you provided. The rest depends on what fails: do you get a WebElement object as a result of that xpath evaluation? 
If yes, then what are you doing with it?
If you don't, I would look at synchronization issues (ie maybe you need to wait for that object).

Comment: thanks, i'll look into that and see what I can come up with,